# iOS WKWebView Peek and Pop on an Image

Tags: ios, uikit, webkit, wkwebview, force-touch

Lately I have been trying to get Peek And Pop to work with my WKWebView. The use case I use it for is a RichText comment section in my App. But because there is already done plenty of customization done to the WebView I setup a [minimal reproducible example](https://github.com/tpgmeligmeyling/StackOverflow-PopAndPeekWebView).

So far I found out the following:

1. The property [allowsLinkPreview](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1415000-allowslinkpreview) of WKWebView should be true, which it defaults to.
2. You should implement a custom [WKUIDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkuidelegate) in which:

   - `webView(_ webView: WKWebView, shouldPreviewElement...` should return true if you want to show a Peek and Pop.
   - `webView(_ webView: WKWebView, previewingViewControllerForElement...` should return the view controller to display for pop and peek.
   - `webView(_ webView: WKWebView, commitPreviewingViewController...` once the peek and pop is completed you should push the view to a navigation controller or present it modally here.

The effect I am trying to achieve is displayed [here](https://youtu.be/JMyHrJ0c6kw).

Problem:
What currently goes wrong is that I do return true from shouldPreviewElement, but then the second method, previewViewControllerForElement is never invoked as expected. I have also looked at other Pop and Peek implementations (outside of WKWebView and they work similarly and do not have this problem).

Comment: Have you found a solution ?

Comment: @S.P. Unfortunately not. I checked out the WebKit source code though and it is a limitation in the WebKit framework. Without a lot of hacks/customization you cannot implement this is my conclusion.